# Changing text in TextView inside CardView from itself

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Imagine a CardView with a button and text field. When I press on a button, text should change in the textfield. Code for my recyclerView is given below, where I am setting the text and a listener for a button:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesDetailedViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final CategoryDetailedModel model = categoriesDetailedModels.get(position);
        holder.description.setText(model.getQuestion());

        holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.description.setText("some text");
            }
        });
    }
```

The main problem is with the string:

```
holder.description.setText("some text");
```

It cannot be accessed from an inner class. 
Is anyone have any idea how to change text in card view from itself.

**Update 1**

```
public class CategoriesDetailedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cv;
        TextView description;
        TextView positiveCounter;
        TextView negativeCounter;
        TextView btnPlus;
        View negativeCounterWrapper;
        View positiveCounterWrapper;
        CategoriesDetailedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            description = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
            positiveCounter = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_positive_count_in_circle);
            negativeCounter = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_negative_count_in_circle);
            btnPlus = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus_button);

            positiveCounterWrapper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.positive_count_wrapper);
            negativeCounterWrapper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.negative_count_wrapper);
            cv.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CategoriesDetailedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.categories_detailed_list_row_view, parent, false);
        CategoriesDetailedViewHolder pvh = new CategoriesDetailedViewHolder(v);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return pvh;
    }
```

Comment: How can't you change the name if the onBind is there for you to manipulate data from the view with the adapter?

Comment: @AntónioPaulo offer me how can I update adapter from itself, because I don't know..

Comment: Please add the code for your ViewHolder. Thanks

Comment: I can achieve what you are asking, but can you give me a sample of your code like Ahmed suggested? Maybe you are using a different approach.

Comment: @Ahmed please check it out

Comment: Make sure your description TextView is public in your ViewHolder and you might need to make your ViewHolder final to be accessible from your clickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of,

```
TextView description;
```

Make it,

```
public TextView description;
```

**EDIT:**
Change the following,

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesDetailedViewHolder holder, int position) { ... }
```

to,

```
@Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder( final CategoriesDetailedViewHolder holder, int position) { .... }
```

Comment: problem in "holder" value, not in TextView value.
Look at this https://snag.gy/QLEbXS

Comment: Make your holder final

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and it works fine, you just need to use onBind method. 
This is one example, I use this in my project and you can just change it to suit your needs:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final TipsViewHolder TipsViewHolder, final int i) {

        TipsViewHolder.cardText.setText("Old text");

        TipsViewHolder.txtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TipsViewHolder.cardText.setText("New Text");

            }
        });
}
```